# How export and re-import a custom process model obtained with inherited model between two different Azure DevOps 2019 cloud environments?

Tags: azure-devops

I configured a custom process model in a cloud envinroment E1 using inherited model.
Is it possibile to export and re-import this custom process model in another cloud environment E2?
Both E1 and E2 are based on same version of Azure DevOps Services 2019.

And what about migration of data contained in work items of E1? Is there a way to migrate data and relations from work items of E1 to E2?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to try out the tools mentioned in below answer? how did it go?

Comment: I have successfully used both tools!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting/importing custom process is not supported in Azure DevOps Services.

However, you can [VSTS Process Migrator tool](https://github.com/microsoft/process-migrator) to export/import the inherited  process template between different Azure DevOps Services organizations.

As for migration of work items data, you can use [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/) to migrate Work Items between different Azure DevOps organizations. You can also check out tool [vsts-work-item-migrator](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-work-item-migrator) to migrate work items.